# Remove html functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text area, when you type into it and press submit, is creates a new post (Div) of what you have written. I was wondering if there is a way to remove any html functions so that the Div shows texts only.

For example if I wrote "< b > Hello < b / >" then "**Hello**" would appear in the Div.

I want it to show the whole code: "< b > Hello < b / >"

Here's my code:
HTML:

```
<textarea rows="8" cols="30" id="textBox" placeholder="What are you doing?" maxlength="180"></textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
//When user clicks submit
$("#centerDiv").prepend("<div id='microBlog'>"+ msgBody +"</div>")
```

Comment: use `pre` or encode into entities.

Comment: Hey that works in a way. But it still doesn't show the html tags.. Hello will still come out in bold.

Answer (score 1):

`msgBody` in your code is set as `innerHTML` of the generated element, you can set it as `textContent` of the element by using the `text` method:

```
$('<div/>', {
  'class': 'microBlog',
  'text': msgBody
}).prependTo('#centerDiv');
```

Note that IDs must be unique, you should use classes instead.

Comment: yeah this sort of works in converting the html into plain text. But you have used 'appendTo' which is wrong is should be 'prepend'. If you are not sure about the difference you could probably do a quick google search and it will help you :)

Comment: @LearnerBeware Changed it to `prependTo`! `prepend` won't work in this case.

Comment: yeah i found the answer and its a lot easier than your way

Answer (score 0):

Here is also an alternative:

```
function copyText(){
    var msgBody = $('#textBox').val();
    $("#centerDiv").prepend($('div').attr('id', 'microBlog').text(msgBody));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

All i had to do was enclose the html in xmp tags. For example:

```
$("#centerDiv").prepend("<div id='microBlog'><xmp>"+ msgBody +"</xmp></div>")
```